# interactive plot on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, plot, jupyter-notebook, interactive

I am trying to obtain an interactive plot but this code's output is totally empty.
If I erase plt.show() I get this output AxesSubplot: without the image

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
xx=float('nan')
data=[['A', 1, xx ],
        ['B', 5,6],
        ['C', 4,6]
        ,['A', 6,xx],
        ['B',9,xx],
        ['C', 7,9]
        ,['A', 2,3],
        ['B', 5,1],
        ['C',2,10]
        ,['B', 8,2],
        ['B', 5,4],
        ['C', 8,5 ]]
dff = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x','y','z'])


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

dff['y'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you try with `%matplotlib` only?

Comment: yes, only with what's in the code

Comment: then I get these messages: 'Using matplotlib backend: nbAgg'  and '<AxesSubplot:>' again

Comment: nothing shows, just those  messages and empty spaces in between.  Sometimes the frame of the graph appears for 1 second and then disappears

Comment: both options output the following message: Warning: Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit: qt. Using notebook instead.

Comment: I see; as said, sorry I'dont have anything else but maybe you can restart the kernel? Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Appreciate it